# Redirect form data in Node app to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, forms, express

Is there any way I can have a form data redirect to a PHP file inside the same folder while using Node & Express.

**HTML**

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nameinput" placeholder="Subject" name="contact-subject">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="emailinput" placeholder="Email" name="contact-email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="contact-message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-big">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

When I click submit it gives me "Cannot POST /contact.php". I know it has something to do with me using Express & Bodyparser.

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client')));
app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('cool stuff on: 8000 check if right server');
});
```

I have tried taking out "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())", but it still gives the same error.

Have replaced the submit button in the form with an **anchor** and changing the form action to ""

```
<a href="contact.php" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-big">Submit</a>
```

it just downloads the contact.php file when submit is clicked.

This is the PHP file im trying to access.

```
<?php
// get posted data into local variables
$EmailTo = "ENTER EMAIL";
$Subject = "Message via Portfolio";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['contact-name'])); 
$EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['contact-email']));  
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['contact-message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (Trim($EmailFrom)=="") $validationOK=false;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<h2>There was an error. Please try to send the message again. </h2>";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "You've got this email from your website:";
$Body .= "\r\n";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\r\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $EmailFrom;
$Body .= "\r\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\r\n";

// send email 
$success = mail( $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body );

//redirect to success page 
if ($success){
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
?>
```

Is there any way to do this instead of using app.post & rewriting the entire php in javascript? . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following to run php (make sure you have a server capable of running PHP).

1. In your node directory where you have `Server.js` create a directory called `php`
2. Move your `contact.php` to `php` directory
3. set form action to the contact.php within php directory
4. in `Server.js` set php drectory as static by `app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'php'));`

Hope this helps.

But while you are on node, use express to handle form data using route.post.